# Transferring money to the Netherlands which has been already taxed in the country of origin

Tags: taxes, netherlands, money-transfer

I am an expat living in The Netherlands and I have the 30% ruling. I have savings in my home country and I have already paid all applicable taxes on them. The amount in consideration is about EUR 40k.

What taxes will I have to pay if I were to transfer this amount to my savings account in the Netherlands, apart from bank transfer and currency conversion fees?

Comment: What is your home country?

Comment: I'm not financial adviser, but you might prove that this is your money and then you will have usual tax on savings if you have more than tax free capital https://www.expatax.nl/box-3

Comment: Would this question get more help from [Money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: There's also the question of whether you'll need to report anything to the tax authority (Belastingdienst). IIANM, salaried workers typically don't file reports; and I myself as a 30%-ruling-expat wasn't requested to do so either.

Answer (score 3):

You will not need to pay any taxes to the Dutch tax office for this money so long as you continue to qualify for the 30% ruling and choose to file as a partial non-resident while having the 30% ruling.

In the Netherlands, savings and investments are taxed under "box 3".  The tax you pay is a percentage of the amount saved and invested.

With the 30% ruling, you can choose to be treated as a partial non-resident for tax purposes.  If you choose this option, you are treated as a non-resident for box 3 taxes:
https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/internationaal/werken_wonen/tijdelijk_in_een_ander_land_werken/u_komt_in_nederland_werken/partiele_buitenlandse_belastingplicht/

For non-residents, the box 3 tax only applies to certain assets that are physically located in the Netherlands such as vacation houses. For non-residents, it does not apply to savings or investments in securities or mutual funds regardless of whether they are in the Netherlands or not. See here:
https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontentnl/belastingdienst/prive/internationaal/fiscale_regelingen/buitenlandse-belastingplicht/welke_gegevens_vult+u_in_uw_aangifte_in/bezittingen_box3/